# Smooth progress bar from video file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a homepage video, and a div to display the progress. The problem tho, is that the progress bar increases in little chunks, I would like it to be smooth, I was thinking of adding an `animate()` to the process. Do you have a better idea?

```
var homepageVideo = $('#homepage_video').get(0);
var progressBar = $('.homepage_progress_bar--progress-bar');
var progressBarContainerWidth = $('.homepage_progress_bar--progress-bar-default').width();
var progress = 0;
var homepageVideoDurationCurrentTime = 0;
var homepageVideoDuration = 0;

homepageVideo.play();

homepageVideo.ontimeupdate = function() {
    updateProgressBar()
};

function updateProgressBar() {
     homepageVideoDurationCurrentTime = homepageVideo.currentTime;
     homepageVideoDuration = homepageVideo.duration;

     progress = getProgress(homepageVideoDurationCurrentTime, homepageVideoDuration);

      progressBar.width(progressBarContainerWidth * progress);
 }

 function getProgress(currentTime, duration) {
     return (100 - (((duration - currentTime) * 100)/duration))/100;
 }
```

My HTML is simply

```
<div class="homepage_progress_bar--progress-bar-default">
    <div class="homepage_progress_bar--progress-bar"></div>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JorgeAnzola/2cegqg5j/)

Comment: Can you provide current state as fiddle?

Comment: Sure! I edited it.

Comment: Please try bootstrap progress bar, I used that once and it provided smooth progress bar. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_progressbar3&stacked=h